# Number of verbs possible in a single sentence

Tags: verbs

Richard Adams, a consultant for McDonald’s franchisees in San Diego, said Thompson’s departure **was** a bit of a surprise considering the numerous plans McDonald’s recently **announced** to turn around its business.

Could you please let me know if the above sentence contains only the two verbs I have **bolded** or if there are others that I have missed. Also, is it possible for two (or more) verbs to occur in a single sentence?

Thanks,
Charmi

Comment: The first sentence of your question contains six verbs, so it's not clear to me what you're asking. Of course a sentence can have multiple verbs and be grammatical. In your example, the main verb is *said*, which you missed, and *to turn* is also a verbal, heading an infinitive phrase. If you would like help parsing the sentence, our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) may be better suited.

Comment: @choster Said, was, considering (progressive participle form), announced, and turn around...five. Am I missing one?

Comment: Charmi, see also [ell.se] Good Luck.

Comment: @pyobum In the original, *could*, *let*, *know*, *is*, *have*, *are*.

Comment: @choster Ah, I thought you were referring to the first sentence (Richard Adams...) of his post.

Comment: @pyobium _Considering_ is now classed as a preposition in the above usage.

Answer (score 2):

*Theoretically*, it is possible to have an infinite numbers of verbs in a single sentence. In actual usage, even simple sentences frequently contain more than one "main verb" in what is called a [compound predicate](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/compound_predicate.htm).

Example:
I *closed* my eyes and *counted* to ten. (Two verbs)

Furthermore, a sentence can contain additional verbs (as in the example sentence you gave) that are part of relative clauses, subordinate clauses, etc.

Example:
(subordinate clause) When I *looked* outside,
(independent clause) I *saw* the terrible damage
(relative clause) that the storm *caused*. (Three verbs total)

In the sentence you posted, there are four verbs *acting as* verbs: *said*, *was*, *announced*, and *turn around* (a phrasal verb). The main subject is *Richard Adams* and the main verb is *said*. The verb *was* is used in a ["reported speech" noun clause](http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/nounclause4.html) and *announced* is used in a [relative (adjective) clause](http://writingcenter.unc.edu/handouts/relative-clauses/) describing "plans." *Turn around* is contained in an [infinitive phrase](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/infinitivephrase.htm) inside of the "announced" relative clause.

Comment: Nice answer. I reformatted to be a bit more in accordance with site policy.

Comment: @medica I was just eyeballing your changes. I was debating whether to go back in and add "total" for clarification in my second example. Thank you for putting it in there. I'm curious about the changes from bold to italic... Is that the preferred style on ELU? And is there a style guide I can refer to for future posts?

Comment: @medica Bold was right per the conventions here, not italics.

Comment: @medica Neither of us is new to the conventions here. Also, there is always the meta.english.stackexchange.com

Comment: @medica Yikes...I hope I wasn't kicking a hornet's nest with my "style" question. I probably have my own laziness to blame for not being well aware of the formatting conventions/preferences here. I'll try to track them down or just start paying closer attention to answer formats from the site's "veterans." And I appreciate your kindness. I find that online communities where the users generally remain civil are few and far between. I plan to stick around, but for now I leave the more complex questions to the 20K+ crowd.

Comment: @medica No worries and no offense taken. I'm relatively new as I'm sure you've noticed, so I'm still learning the ropes here and there.

Comment: @CharmiSapariya You're welcome. And please do check out the English Language Learners site mentioned above. You'll find many of the users from this site are active on that one as well (including me). It's a good resource when general reference materials aren't enough.

Comment: @Pyobum,Thank you for your suggestion. Either you are asking to refer to other questions those are similer to my question (No. of Verbs) that i have asekd here or i could have approched to active user on the site.

Comment: @CharmiSapariya I'm not quite sure what you mean. I referred you to English Language Learners for any *future* questions like the one you asked here.

Comment: @medica I chanced upon these... http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/363/what-emphasis-to-use-when-referring-to-words/364#364
http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4720/color-of-certain-elements-in-main-site-doesnt-match-up-with-the-rest-of-the-pag/4722#4722

Comment: @pyobum - very nice! :-)  I asked a mod, and it seems there is no style guide; the closest I've found is occasional 'advice' similar to your finds. Thanks for posting (and remembering!) I was wondering if I had invented it all!